# Inherited Common Class Properties using Entity framework Core Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two classes called PositionTitle and JobPosition which has common properties. I would like to add all common properties of both classes
in a parent class and inherit parent class in both PositionTitle and JobPosition child classes. Please note that, I am using Entity Framwork Core  Migration with Configuration. Below is my code with PositionTitle and JobPosition classes.

```
 public class PositionTitleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PositionTitle>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PositionTitle> entity)
        {
            entity.ToTable("PositionTitle", "HR");
            entity.HasKey("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.EnglishName).HasColumnName("EnglishName").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar"); 
            entity.Property(c => c.Code).HasColumnName("Code").IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnType("nvarchar");

            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn").IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").HasColumnType("bit");
            entity.Property(c => c.Remarks).HasColumnName("Remarks").IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(500).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
        }
    }

 public class JobPositionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobPosition>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobPosition> entity)
        {
            entity.ToTable("JobPosition", "HR");
            entity.HasKey("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.EnglishName).HasColumnName("EnglishName").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar"); 
            entity.Property(c => c.Code).HasColumnName("Code").IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnType("nvarchar");

            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn").IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").HasColumnType("bit");
            entity.Property(c => c.Remarks).HasColumnName("Remarks").IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(500).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
        }
    }
```

I need the code something like this:
Parrent Class: BasePositionJob (which includes all the common properties of PositionTitle and JobPosition classes)

```
public class BasePositionJob
{           entity.HasKey("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
            entity.Property(c => c.EnglishName).HasColumnName("EnglishName").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("nvarchar"); 
            entity.Property(c => c.Code).HasColumnName("Code").IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(50).HasColumnType("nvarchar");

            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedBy).HasColumnName("CreatedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CreatedOn").IsRequired(true).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedBy).HasColumnName("ModifiedBy").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("UNIQUEIDENTIFIER");
            entity.Property(c => c.ModifiedOn).HasColumnName("ModifiedOn").IsRequired(false).HasColumnType("DateTime");
            entity.Property(c => c.IsDeleted).HasColumnName("IsDeleted").HasColumnType("bit");
            entity.Property(c => c.Remarks).HasColumnName("Remarks").IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(500).HasColumnType("nvarchar");
}
Child Class: PositionTitle (this class should inherit parent class BasePositionJob)
  public class PositionTitleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<PositionTitle>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PositionTitle> entity)
        {  
           entity.ToTable("PositionTitle", "HR");
        }
    }
```

Child Class: JobPosition (this class should also inherit parent class BasePositionJob)

```
 public class JobPositionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<JobPosition>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<JobPosition> entity)
        {
         entity.ToTable("JobPosition", "HR");
        }
    }
```

I am not able to inherit properties from BasePositionJob to both PositionTitle and JobPosition classes.

Comment: EF Core supports inheritance, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.